# PHP Elasticsearch: wildcard query won't find any results

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Im trying to use a wildcard for a specific column in my elasticsearch document. However, doing so, nothing happens. Elasticsearch doesn't find any results.

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

How my search query looks like:

```
array:3 [
  "index" => "certificates"
  "type" => "_doc"
  "body" => array:3 [
    "from" => 0
    "size" => 25
    "query" => array:1 [
      "wildcard" => array:1 [
        "product_name" => array:1 [
          "value" => "Fra*"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I don't see any difference to what the elasticsearch documentation recommends me.

**PHP Version:** 7.1.3

**Elasticsearch version:** 6.7.0

**Response from elasticsearch when searching:**

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Sample data inside of a document:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a document that you think should match?

Comment: Just did. Hope it helps.

Comment: Misunderstood this a little.

I've showed the strucutre of any document.

The actual value of ```product_name```shouldnt matter at all. I know what I've stored and what I'am looking for. Even if--let's say product_name has a value of "King sized Burger"--entering "King sized Burger" doesnt result in anything too. It just doesnt work somehow.

Comment: I meant a sample document with data in it.

Comment: Replaced the image with an actual document.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't solve it with wildcards--still not working--however, it works with `query_string`

```
            'query_string' => [
                'query' => 'product_name:' . $request->product_name . '*',
                'default_operator' => 'AND'
            ]
```